# Find the growth of the same name in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset:

```
Year Name Value
1    A    10
2    B    20
3    A    25
3    B    10
```

I want to be able to find how each name has changed over the years. Ideally the result should look like

```
Name Growth/Year
A    (25-10)/(3-1)
B    (10-20)/(3-2)
```

I can build a list of unique name first, and then loop through the dataset to find the value change. But is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using pandas `groupby`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[1,2,3,3], 'name':['A','B','A','B'], 'value':[10,20,25,10]})

df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: (x['value'].iloc[1]-x['value'].iloc[0])/(x['year'].iloc[1]-x['year'].iloc[0]))

>>>

name
A     7.5
B    -10.0
dtype: float64
```

Or to have more flexibility, you could define an aggregation function:

```
def value_change(x):
    
    yr1 = min(x['year'])
    yr2 = max(x['year'])
    
    # Get values corresponding to min and max years in case
    # min and max year rows aren't contiguous
    value1 = x[x['year']==yr1]['value'].iloc[0]
    value2 = x[x['year']==yr2]['value'].iloc[0]
    
    return (value2-value1)/(yr2-yr1)

df.groupby('name').apply(value_change)
```

Answer (score 0):

So first you want the rows the which correspond to the first and last year for each name:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,"A", 10], [2, "B", 20], [3, "A", 25], [3, "B", 10]], columns=["Year", "Name", "Value"])
first_year = df.groupby("Name").Year.idxmin().sort_index()
last_year = df.groupby("Name").Year.idxmax().sort_index()
```

I added the `sort_index` just to be sure that the order lines up but it might be a good idea to test this to make sure that nothing went wrong. Here's how I would test it:

```
assert (first_year.index == last_year.index).all()
```

Next, you can use these to extract the values you want and compute the change:

```
change_value = (df.loc[last_year.values, "Value"].values - df.loc[first_year.values, "Value"].values)
change_time = (df.loc[last_year.values, "Year"].values - df.loc[first_year.values, "Year"].values)
change_over_time = change_value / change_time
```

Then, you can convert this into pandas frame if you'd like:

```
pd.Series(change_over_time, index=first_year.index)
```

There probably a tidier way to do this all within the `groupby` but I think this way easier to understand.